# How to display list of checkboxes on button click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am referring to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9HXzW/55/ which is written using Jquery.

The code in HTML is,

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
    <ol>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 5</li> 
    </ol>
</div>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>Show Check Box</span></a>
```

and the jquery is,

```
 $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(0)').hide();
$('a.button').on("click", function() { 
    $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(0)').slideToggle(); 
});
```

I want the functionality in angularjs where on clicking a button, the button should toggle and display a list of checkboxes. What changes should i make in the fiddle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On click of button just toogle the value of `displayCheckBox`. Rest will be handled by angularjs

```
<div ng-show="displayCheckBox">
    <ol>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"/>Check box 5</li> 
    </ol>
</div>

<a class="button" href="#" ng-click="displayCheckBox=!displayCheckBox"><span>Show Check Box</span></a>
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/R78mVS9xs3a6gBbT2TZS?p=preview)**</kbd>